# live datatables records, displaying data with classes and data binding envolves in table row or td

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im using [datatables](http://datatables.net) and I came across for a self requirements where I want a live table data and I use datatables for this requirements, however Im having an issue when displaying the pulled data from the server to the table. Surely I can use:

```
$('#ua_table').DataTable().row.add(['Sample name', 'Sample address', 'Sample Job', 'Sample Contact', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', '<button>asd</button>']).draw();
```

to populate the table tbody with the new data with the help of each function but the problem is there is a data binding and classes involves in each table row (tr) and might be also in td. How can I display the new data with data binding or classes to each tr or td? like this (refer below)

```
<tr class="' + value.holder + '" class="' + value.classes + '"><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.address + '</td><td>' + value.job + '</td><td>' + value.contact + '</td></tr>
```

Any ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations, help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ua_table').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    });
  
  $(".load").click(function(){
    $('#ua_table').dataTable().fnClearTable(); //clear the table first
    $.post("/test", { id: "1" }, function(response){ //pull the new data
            if(response.success){
                var bbr = $("#ua_table tbody");
                bbr.html("");
                $.each(response.persons, function(index, value){
                    bbr.append('<tr class="' + value.holder + '" class="' + value.classes + '"><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.address + '</td><td>' + value.job + '</td><td>' + value.contact + '</td></tr>');
                });
                                
            }
        }, 'json');
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="ua_table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 1</td>
      <td>Sample address 1</td>
      <td>Sample job 1</td>
      <td>Sample contact 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 2</td>
      <td>Sample address 2</td>
      <td>Sample job 2</td>
      <td>Sample contact 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 3</td>
      <td>Sample address 3</td>
      <td>Sample job 3</td>
      <td>Sample contact 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

<button class="load">Load ajax</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option to define a callback function that will be called when a new row is created to set classes, add event handlers, etc.

See the example below for demonstration on how to set class for both `<tr>` and `<td>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ua_table').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "address" },
            { "data": "job" },
            { "data": "contact" }
        ],
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
           $(row).addClass(data.classes);  
          
           $('td:eq(2)', row).addClass(data.holder);
        }
    });
  
  $(".load").click(function(){
    $('#ua_table').DataTable().clear();
    
/*    
    $.post("/test", { id: "1" }, function(response){ //pull the new data
            if(response.success){
                var bbr = $("#ua_table tbody");
                bbr.html("");
                $.each(response.persons, function(index, value){
                    bbr.append('<tr class="' + value.holder + '" class="' + value.classes + '"><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.address + '</td><td>' + value.job + '</td><td>' + value.contact + '</td></tr>');
                });
                                
            }
        }, 'json');
*/
     $('#ua_table').DataTable().row.add(
       {
         name:'Sample name', 
         address: 'Sample address', 
         job: 'Sample Job', 
         contact: 'Sample Contact', 
         holder: 'error', 
         classes: 'warning'
       }
     ).draw();
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
td.error { 
  background-color:#FCC !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="ua_table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 1</td>
      <td>Sample address 1</td>
      <td>Sample job 1</td>
      <td>Sample contact 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 2</td>
      <td>Sample address 2</td>
      <td>Sample job 2</td>
      <td>Sample contact 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample name 3</td>
      <td>Sample address 3</td>
      <td>Sample job 3</td>
      <td>Sample contact 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

<button class="load">Load ajax</button>
```

However, I don't think you have to use a separate `$.post`, `clear()` and `row.add()`. DataTables handles Ajax-sourced data by itself, see [Ajax data source (objects)](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) example. All you need to do is to use [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) to reload the data when necessary.

Comment: seems too long and complicated to a first time datatables user like me, anyway great code, so where im gonna insert my post ajax there?

Comment: @CodeDemon, It's commented out, but you can insert the `row.add()` code into `$.each(response.persons, function(index, value){` function but instead of `'Sample name'` use `value.name` and so forth.

Comment: @CodeDemon, I think you don't have to use a separate `$.post`, `clear()` and `row.add()`, this is overly complicated unless it's really necessary. See notes in my answer for more details.